# Is there a way to create a loop, that will search for an element; If that element is not found then an "else/elif" would run?

Tags: python

I want to search for an element in an online game, the element will only appear randomly after I move my character.

```
elements = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('p > .button-maroon')    

while True:
    if elements.is_displayed():
        print('found it!')
        time.sleep(5)
except NoSuchElementException:
        time.sleep(2)
        pg.press('s')
```

I get an error that says, Unable to locate element. Obviously, the element is not there therefore, it should move onto the next line, which is to press the S button and loop back until the element is found. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
elements = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('p > .button-maroon')    

while True:
    try:
        if elements.is_displayed():
            print('found it!')
            time.sleep(5)
            break
    except NoSuchElementException:
            time.sleep(2)
            pg.press('s')
```

Don't go crazy with your bots, make sure the game is happy with you doing this before you do it. :-)

Comment: I get an error, Message: no such element: Unable to locate element. I'm not sure why the code won't continue to the next line

Answer (score 1):

You can use until method and wait for element

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

the code will be like this:

```
while True:
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'p > .button-maroon'))
    )
        print('found it!')
        time.sleep(5)
    except Exception:
        time.sleep(2)
        pg.press('s')
```

Comment: I've tried explicit wait but it wouldn't work because the element that I am looking for will only populate randomly after movement in the game

Comment: But you're in a while, so it will search all the time, right?

Comment: Yeah I am in a While True but it doesn't seem to loop